# How to enable Continuous Deployment to an internal server from BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket, devops, continuous-deployment, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I need some guidance and advice please on if / how I can implement a CI / CD pipeline for a corporate PHP Laravel application that is hosted on an internal server with limited access and no public IP. Unfortunately my DevOps knowledge is limited and despite a lot of Google searches, I have no idea if I am on the right track or if I am a million miles away. Everything that I have read so far looks at using Web Hooks which as far as I can tell are reliant on a public IP / domain.

At present I can work on the application on my laptop and push changes to BitBucket Cloud. While I have managed to create a bitbucket-pipelines.yml file that will automatically build and test any branches that are pushed, I then have to access the server to pull the code manually and run the various scripts as required, which I would much prefer to automate.

I need to understand please what options there are for implementing continuous deployment given the circumstances and limitations?

If anyone could offer some pointers then I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "public IP"? That it's not connected to the internet?

Comment: @Randommm - Yes, it is hosted internally on a virtual machine. By default our security team lock down all access to the outside world unless we request otherwise. For example, I am allowed to pull from Bitbucket as they have permitted outbound access to that URL. The challenge I am facing now is how to "trigger" the server to pull code, run scripts etc on a successful build.

Comment: Well if you can't get a connection to it from the outside then you can't call it to do so... Maybe if you would have a another computer that can ssh into the machine could work as a proxy to call for the script to be run

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/77960614/11715259

Answer (score 2):

You can't push to a machine that is unreachable but there are some alternatives.

- Configure a **bastion host**, so an external CI/CD runner can ssh through it into your server. Allow inbound port 22 connections from your CI/CD provider CIDR blocks to your bastion host https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/
- Setup a CI/CD **self-hosted runner** in the same network than the server. https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/runners/ Use that runner for the deployment step to ssh into your server **private IP address**.
- Setup a **pull-based deployment strategy**. Your deployment step only registers the new wanted version, e.g. moving a `release/production` branch on the commit ref where the deploy was triggered. In your server, setup some kind of subscription to the latest release/deployment, e.g. a cron task to frequently fetch the production git branch. Upon changes, restart services and run any task you need. [`ansible-pull`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html) can be handy for this purpose.