# Bitbucket pipeline SSH key setting: Can't fetch host fingerprints

Tags: continuous-integration, ssh-keys, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to set up ssh keys for my pipeline and send files of the artifacts of my build step to an embedded device using scp deploy pipe. I generated the ssh key in the repository settings and copied the public key into the authorized_keys files of my embedded device following https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-pipelines-ssh-keys-on-windows/. However when i try to fetch the known host finger print (using the embedded device's ip address), it loads for a moment and nothing happens. There is no error message or any fingerprint fetched. The scp deployment pipe also fails because host key verification failed. My embedded devices have their own wifi (without internet) but are connected and discoverable on my network (with internet). I also run my pipeline on a self-hosted linux docker runner, which on that linux machine i am able to connect to the devices via ssh just fine. I am unsure where does bitbucket executes this fetch fingerprint process (My runner server / their own bitbucket server / my laptop) and am wondering if the device ip are not discoverable there.

I am relatively new to pipelines and ssh so i am quite lost as to what went wrong.

[The fetch fingerprint buffers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LsDd.png)
[Doesn't show any error or fingerprints after buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0dgL.png)

I tried creating the ssh key pair manually following the documentation's instructions and still i cannot connect with ssh/scp from my pipeline. I ensured the permissions of the .ssh and authorized_keys files are 700 and 600 respectively. Similarly i am not able to fetch the known host fingerprints.

Comment: The IP you want to add to fingerprints is a local one and thus cannot be added. The identification goes thru their system and is most likely blocked as it would be THEIR local network device. What your pipeline runs on is irrelevant to that issue

Comment: Have you tried making a connection via normal SSH command instead of using pipes?

Comment: Very related https://stackoverflow.com/q/75294376/11715259

Comment: The question could help some formatting, give some structure to that long paragraph and rewrite the title to be an actual headline of your issue (think about people with your similar setup, how would they relate to your question?)

Comment: The "scp deployment pipe also fails because host key verification failed" statement is clear proof that the issue isn't runner--host connectivity nor key-pair setup so you'd better remove any key-pair setup related information because that makes the question less focused.

Comment: Explain that you were holding to the hypothesis that the fingerprint might be fetched by your browser when you tried to fetch a LAN address from Bitbucket's web UI but that didn't work. This can be inferred from your current text but because it is not explicit enough some people might be slightly offended by your question if they don't grasp that.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question for a valid setup that has actual devoted documentation in other CI systems like Gitlab-CI and is a valuable document for the [bitbucket-pipelines] tag corpus. While not the best question, it does not lack details nor clarity in a way that prevents understanding and answering it so I vouch for NOT CLOSING it. Please give this new contributor the opportunity to improve the quality of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess always was that SSH fingerprints are fetched from the server, be it your on-premise hardware or Atlassian's Bitbucket Cloud ® infrastructure. Not from your self-hosted pipeline runner (how would you choose it?) and definitely not from your laptop.

So, to the question on how to fetch ssh fingerprints for intranet hosts, I imagine three solutions.

1. If you were using an on-premise Bitbucket server, the hosts you put in its same network should be discoverable. This is a very tailored solution to setup and I'd advise against it. But if this happened to be your current setup already... I think fetching from the web UI should work.
2. Forward some ports to intranet ssh hosts in your firewall. Just fetch your intranet public-facing IP address + each forwarded port. IMHO a suboptimal approach as this can be against many sensible security policies even if you whitelisted [Atlassian's public IP ranges](https://support.atlassian.com/organization-administration/docs/ip-addresses-and-domains-for-atlassian-cloud-products/#IP-address-ranges).
3. My choice: fetch the ssh from your computer and save the result in a file in your git repository! `ssh-keyscan intranet-address >> ./known_hosts`. Then, in the pipeline script append that file to the one that possibly contains fingerprints that were discoverable from the web UI:

```yaml
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Hi intranet
        runs-on:
          - self.hosted
        script:
          - cat ./known_hosts >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.8.0
            variables:
              SSH_USER: daniel
              SERVER: intranet-address
              COMMAND: echo hello
```

Suffice to say, this is only useful if your pipeline runs in a self-hosted runner in the same actual network as those remote hosts! Otherwise refer to [How to enable Continuous Deployment to an internal server from BitBucket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75294376/11715259)

Also, if your computer needed some kind of NAT to reach those intranet hosts, most probably you will need to manipulate the names, addresses and ports that are recorded in the known_hosts file. It is imperative that it lists the names, addresses and ports that will be apparent to your self-hosted runner instead of your computer.

Related resources: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#verifying-the-ssh-host-keys

---

The key pair generated from the web UI should work just fine if you already put it in the right `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files.